# vlookup from different workbook and dynamic row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use vlookup in Target workbook from a source workbook. Row in Target workbook is dynamic and can change every month.

```
Cells(startRow, lastColumn + 1).Formula = _
     "=VLOOKUP(B " & startRow & ", '[" & fileName & "]ITD Sheet'!B:B, 1, 0)"
```

This however gives application defined or object defined error.

Comment: Application defined or Object defined error (1004)

Comment: What does `Debug.Print "=VLOOKUP(B " & startRow & ", '[" & fileName & "]ITD Sheet'!B:B, 1, 0)"` return in the Immediate Window? Side note, probably should remove the space after `B`, before `startRow`.

Comment: =VLOOKUP(@B&@ startRow, '[Amazon.xlsb]ITD Sheet'!B:B, 1, 0)

Comment: It worked. That space was the problem. Thanks